# How do I change the theme?

Tags: 11.04, themes, appearance

What do I use to change the theme in Ubuntu 11.04 Desktop the previous way through appearance icon is gone.

Comment: Please separate these into two different questions.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

11.04 with Unity: hit <kbd>super + a</kbd> and start typing `appearance`. It will come back with this:

[image]

11.10 should be the same.

Alternatively you can go to the `logout` button, `system settings` and it will be under 'Personal`:

[image]

I think I read in 11.10 this method have been moved elsewhere.

And to make sure it is installed. Open a terminal and type `locate appearance`. It should at least show a line with `/usr/bin/gnome-appearance-properties`. If not appearances is not installed and you could try Ubuntu Software Center to search for it. If it does type `gnome-appearance-properties` and see if that shows it.

Comment: Tried typing appearance after pressing the super key and it say's nothing found and I don't get the results you do in the picture.

Comment: I clicked on the logout button and I am not offered a settings choice either.

Comment: So any other thoughts?

Comment: see my `super + a ` edit. Can you try that too please?

Comment: I pressed super + a and then typed appearance and still came up with nothing. I am still lost on this.

Comment: @user5501 11.10 is in ALPHA still. Features haven't been locked down and it's likely to change in the future.

Comment: locate appearance returned :

Comment: did not return /usr/bin/gnome-appearance-properties

Comment: if that did not return is it is NOT installed on your system. So if you are asking this about 11.04 install it. If you ask this for 11.10 (like it showed initially in your q ;) ) you need to wait until it is included in 11.10 or check a change log for what it is changed into.

Comment: searching for  gnome-appearance-properties in synaptic and ubuntu software center came up with nothing but it is list as part of gnome-control-center and that is installed so I don't understand why it is not found

Comment: Yes I can't get it to work in either both say it is not there.

Comment: So any more thoughts since I can't find it on either distro. 11.04 and 11.10. Is there a way to do this with something else or like with gconf?